No puedo hacer funcionar PYMODBUS
Quiero comunicar un dispositivo MODBUS RTU con la PC a través de Python. Es la primera vez que lo intento con Python y para ello leí un poco y elegí PYMODBUS. Antes de meterme con Python usé un cliente modbus para probar todo el hardware y los parámetros de comunicación, y determiné que los valores son puerto: COM4, baudrate 9600, paridad "EVEN", stopbit 1, frame:RTU.
import pymodbus
import asyncio
from pymodbus.client import AsyncModbusSerialClient

async def Com_Mod_RTU ():
  client = AsyncModbusSerialClient ("COM4",baudrate=9600,parity="E")
  if await client.connect():            # connect to device, reconnect automatically
      result = await client.read_input_registers(address=44151,count=1,slave=1)
      client.close()  
      print(result)                            # use information
  else:
      print("no se conecto")    
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      asyncio.run(Com_Mod_RTU())

Me leí mil veces la documentación de PYMODBUS desde hace 2 semanas y no logro hacerlo funcionar. Creo que ahora estoy bastante cerca, pero con el código que les estoy compartiendo me tira el error "io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno"
Alguno sería tan amable de ayudarme a entender que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

en qué línea te tira el error? podrías compartir todo el mensaje de error en un formato de texto legible?

Hola Diego, yo al menos no puedo reproducir tu error en Linux, pero mírate: https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/discussions/2176 y https://github.com/pymodbus-dev/pymodbus/pull/2191, es posible que esté relacionado. ¿Que versión de Python usas? ¿Has probado con otras?

Gracias a los dos por darme una mano. Voy a intentar responder todo en este mensaje.El error me tira en la línea 8.

'Seguimiento de la pila:
File "C:\Users\diego\source\repos\COMUNICACION_MODBUS\COMUNICACION_MODBUS\COMUNICACION_MODBUS.py", line 8, in Com_Mod_RTU (Current frame)
result = await client.read_input_registers(address=44151,count=1,slave=1)
File "C:\Users\diego\source\repos\COMUNICACION_MODBUS\COMUNICACION_MODBUS\COMUNICACION_MODBUS.py", line 16, in 
asyncio.run(Com_Mod_RTU())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno'

mi versión de Python es la 3.12

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no dejes el código, mensajes de error o trazas de pila que se te piden en comentarios, debes [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código, mensajes de error y stack traces como texto en ella, que es a dónde pertenecen. Estos comentarios solo son ruido y debieran ser eliminados o, cuando menos, ignorados a la postre.
